# Доступ по ключу к массиву из json

Tags: php

Есть код, который берёт данные из json в массив, но при обращении по ключу к такому массиву доступ по ключу не работает.

```
$json = '{"1411":"фыафыва фвафыв","1410":"","1409":"","1411":"фыафыва фвафыв","1410":"tersy","1409":""}';
$images = (array)json_decode(stripslashes($json));

$ids = array (
    0 => '1411',
    1 => '1410',
);

$arr = array();

if(!empty($images)){
    foreach ($ids as $id){
        $arr[$id] = $images[$id];
    }
}
echo 'arr';
echo '<div><pre>';
echo var_export($arr,true);
echo '</pre></div>';
echo 'images';
echo '<div><pre>';
echo var_export($images,true);
echo '</pre></div>';
```

В результате вывод такой:

```
arr
array (
    1411 => NULL,
    1410 => NULL,
)
images
array (
    '1411' => 'фыафыва фвафыв',
    '1410' => 'tersy',
    '1409' => '',
)
```

а должно быть так:

```
array (
    1411 => 'фыафыва фвафыв',
    1410 => 'tersy',
)
```

как исправить подскажите?
пытался конвертировать ключ `$id` в строку, безрезультатно

Comment: Этот код выводит все как надо

Comment: А вот (array)json_decode(stripslashes($json)); - это конечно дикость. должно быть `json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: и вместо echo var_export($images,true); должно быть просто `var_export($images);`

Comment: Как минимум у вас не валидный json.

Comment: JSON данные у вас не массив, а объект. Если вам нужен массив, то декодируйте как ассоциативный массив (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.. Также учтите тип данных - в одном случае у вас строка, а в другом - цифра.

Comment: @Ипатьев, а причём здесь риторический вопрос? я с json мало работал, была полезная информация

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в способе, которым декодируется json.

Если делать по-человечески, а именно

```
$images = json_decode($json, true);
```

то код будет работать в любой версии РНР.